# Issues implementing SQLite and Cursor in an Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an activity which shows 3 random images from JSON data off the Web. Each random image is clickable and leads to its details activity, carrying its title, image, description, etc. The shown images are distinct from each other.

I need to implement SQLite and a `Cursor` to that activity so that whenever there's no internet connection, the application reads the image data from the cache on the external storage. I already have the classes of the database, provider and sync. I have an SQLite database with the following columns:

- `BaseColumns._ID`
- `Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE`

Here are the snippets of code that I have so far:

```
void doSync() {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, LooserSync.class);
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

This method calls the Web service where I put my URL. This is the image is loaded:

```
public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
    v.setTag(value);
    loader.DisplayImage(value, context, v);
}
```

This is my old function that randomizes the images and makes them clickable:

```
prjcts = new ArrayList<Project>();
int max = prjcts.size();
System.out.println(max);
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>(max);
for(int c = 1; c < max; ++c) {
    indices.add(c);
}
Random r = new Random();
int arrIndex = r.nextInt(indices.size());
int randomIndex1 = indices.get(arrIndex);
indices.remove(arrIndex);
```

This is what I have in my activity so far:

```
int arrIndex2 = r.nextInt(indices.size());
int randomIndex2 = indices.get(arrIndex2);
indices.remove(arrIndex2);

int arrIndex3 = r.nextInt(indices.size());
int randomIndex3 = indices.get(arrIndex3);
indices.remove(arrIndex3);

imageLazy(image1, prjcts.get(randomIndex1),Main.this);
imageLazy(image2, prjcts.get(randomIndex2),Main.this);
imageLazy(image3, prjcts.get(randomIndex3),Main.this);

image1.setOnClickListener(new RandomClickListener(randomIndex1));
image2.setOnClickListener(new RandomClickListener(randomIndex2));
image3.setOnClickListener(new RandomClickListener(randomIndex3));

public void imageLazy(final ImageView image,Project pro,Activity activity) {
     String imageurl = pro.smallImageUrl;
     image.setTag(imageurl);
     loader.DisplayImage(imageurl, activity,image);
}

public class RandomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
     private final int randomIndex;

     public RandomClickListener(final int randomIndex) {
           this.randomIndex = randomIndex;
     }
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent top = new Intent(Main.this, DetailsActivity.class);
          top.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position", randomIndex);
          /*
          top.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
          LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long.toString(id)));
           */
          startActivity(top);
     }
}
```

Here is a function that retrieves the image details:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath( LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long .toString(id));

Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( uri, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, Database.Project.C_BIGIMAGE }, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 3");
```

Any suggestions on how to build the code from these snippets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for FSM's sake use ListView with query like this

```
Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery( //it seems like you should change your internship
                uri, //to somthing esier than programming
                projection,    // Which columns to return.
                null,          // WHERE clause.
                null,          // WHERE clause value substitution
                "RANDOM() LIMIT 3");
```

with this query u get top 3 rows from Project table in random order

EDIT:

1. use ListView
2. wrong uri ... you didn't made your homework (by reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)). Try this one. `Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath( LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME));`
3. About using Cursors:

   Cursor c = query();

   if(c.moveToFirst()){

   ```
   do{

       //do something with current row like c.getString(1);

   }while(c.moveToNext());
   ```

   }
4. but why oh why you don't using ListView

EDIT2:
chang similar lines in [my sample for looser](http://esilo.pl/loosersample.zip) to:

```
    listView.setAdapter(new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.itemrow,
            managedQuery(Uri.withAppendedPath(LooserProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                    Database.Project.NAME), new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
                    Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE,
                    Database.Project.C_ORGANIZATIONTITLE,
                    Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, null, null, "RANDOM() LIMIT 3"),
            new String[] { Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE,
                    Database.Project.C_ORGANIZATIONTITLE,
                    Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.tName, R.id.tDescription, R.id.iItem }));
```

you can do Menu->Synchronize to see what happend

get rid of text from listrow and you got your program

Comment: so I tried something out, you can look up my updated question..what do I need more?

Comment: Thanks, I will try. I dont use listview because I need to display it not as a listview, I only need to show 3 images and it must be horizontal

Comment: using the EDIT2 is actually a smart idea, and now I'm trying to figure it out how the list view could be horizontal. And most importantly, when I click the random list it should lead me to its detailsactivity, not the details based on the entry position on the json

Comment: 1. it's hard to build horizontal ListView ... 2. you clicking on image and then you got details about this particular action(this is how my example works) or to ListActivity with all entries?

Comment: 1. I'm figuring out 2.to go to the details like your example does. But by changing the adapter only, it goes always to the detail of the 1st entry on the json data, not the detail of the random shown image.

Comment: 1. Found this solution for the horizontal listview :) http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to ask a question that is relatively simple to answer.
Most people won't want to produce code for you.

Comment: You should write this as comment instead of writing it as answers